# Process started with QProcess doesn’t exit if we close the main application

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Suppose I start a process in terminal in Linux, if the terminal is closed the child process started in terminal also exits (even if process is started using sudo). But if I start a process (say) `p1` using `QProcess` inside a `GUI` application, and then close the `gui` application, process `p1` still keeps running, as if it is a daemon, even if I don’t start the process using `QProcess::startDetached()`.

```
process1->start("gksudo",args);
```

and

```
process1->terminate();
process1->close();
```

in closeEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
delete process1;
```

in GUI class destructor.

Comment: I did that but of no use! Perhaps we can't send signals to processes we don't own! gksudo makes the root to own the process!

Comment: @adnan: yes, you can't terminate or kill process you don't own (unless yoe're root). You can test it by trying to kill process from console - you'll fail because you don't enough privileges.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing your QProcess? When I did the following (on Windows) in `mainwindow.cpp` my child process closed when I closed my main application.

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess(this);
proc->start("notepad.exe q:/blah2.txt");
```

By making MainWindow a parent of QProcess, MainWindow will destroy and close it during its QObject destructor.

Comment: Someone running Linux will have to confirm your troubles, then. Everything I see on Windows and in the documentation indicates that that's how you do it—setting the parent in the constructor.